# How do I run Ruby daemons as a specific user?

Tags: ruby, daemons

I am trying to run a Ruby daemon using the `daemons` gem.

It will be started as user 'joe' but needs to change to 'www-data' once it's demonized so that it can access the files it will be working on.

I can see that daemons has `change_privilege` method for the Application class, but I can't figure out how to use it around this code:

```
require 'daemons'
Daemons.run(
  File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'worker.rb'),
  {
    :backtrace  => true,
    :log_output => true,
    :dir_mode   => :script,
    :log_dir    => '/tmp',
    :monitor    => true
  }
)
```

Comment: just FYI. A process started by user "joe" will not be able to change is userid to "www-data".  It will need to be started by the root user.

Comment: You are correct, joe was just an example :)

Comment: the way I normally handle the above is to either user the OS facility to setuid it in the startup script.  or set the effective ID in something like god.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be running as `www-data` as this is a specific user to apache. You should however add "joe" to your www user group that can access such files.